# How to set the counter to 0 again after button click?

Tags: python, tkinter, counter

I have here a function for a counter.

My question is how to set the counter to `0` again after a button click.

```
import tkinter
import sys

root=tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("His Button Increaser")

counter=tkinter.IntVar()

def OnClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text="One up", command=onClick).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean, "after button click"? You increment the counter when you click the button, what sense does it make to set it to zero right away again?

Comment: You question is unclear. As @tobias_k said you are already doing something on button click. Are you asking for a timer that will set the counter to zero if you wait to long to click the button? Or for another button that will reset the counter? Please ad some more context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you are asking. If you want to reset the counter some time after the button has been clicked, you can add a call to `after` at the end of the function:

```
def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)
    root.after(3000, lambda: counter.set(0))
```

This will start a countdown the first time the button is clicked (and every other time thereafter) and reset the counter to `0` when the countdown finishes. Note that the countdown itself is not reset with later clicks, though.

If you do not want the `after` callbacks to stack, you can keep a reference to the ID of the last after event and cancel it before issuing the next one:

```
last_after = None
def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

    global last_after
    if last_after:
        root.after_cancel(last_after)
    last_after = root.after(3000, lambda: counter.set(0))
```

Comment: If this is the rout the OP is wanting to go maybe it should be best to save a reference to the `after()` event and update it each time the button is clicked. This will make is so the event only fires after the last click of the button.